# Stripe Payment: Can't update Tokes

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, stripe-payments

I’m trying to do next: upon successful payment update the tokens (context) and display them in the user panel component. Currently, I am parsing the user input (purchasedCoins) to an integer and setting purchasedCoins equal to the quantity. If the quantity is less than 0, I want to throw an error, otherwise, I want to save the quantity to localStorage and update the tokens using setTokens(quantity). I have been struggling with this for two days and would appreciate any help.
followed stripe docs and built the backend but had no success something fishy going on. In the code, I provided it only needs the frontEnd because it redirects to the stripe on click

**Problem: the code don't updates tokens**

```html
const { tokens, setTokens } = useContext(TokensContext);
  const [purchasedCoins, setPurchasedCoins] = useState(0);

  const handleTokenChange = (e) => {
    setPurchasedCoins(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleBuyClick = async () => {
    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    const quantity = parseInt(purchasedCoins);
    console.log("quantity:", quantity);
    if (quantity > 0) {
      const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        lineItems: [{ price: "price_Moded For Stack", quantity }],
        mode: "payment",
        successUrl: `${window.location.origin}/UserPanel`,
        cancelUrl: `${window.location.origin}/UserPanel`,
      });
      console.log("error:", error);
      if (!error) {
        console.log("updating tokens:", quantity);
        setTokens(quantity);
      }
      console.log(
        "localStorage.tokenQuantity:",
        window.localStorage.getItem("tokenQuantity")
      );
      window.localStorage.setItem("tokenQuantity", quantity);
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid quantity value");
    }
  };
  
  
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------
  //Updated code only updates tokens until page refereshed

  const handleBuyClick = async () => {
    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    const quantity = parseInt(purchasedCoins) || 0;

    if (quantity > 0) {
      const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        lineItems: [{ price: "price_Moded For Stack", quantity }],
        mode: "payment",
        successUrl: `${window.location.origin}/UserPanel`,
        cancelUrl: `${window.location.origin}/UserPanel`,
      });
      if (!error) {
        console.log("success: Updating token quantity");
        const currentQuantity = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("tokenQuantity")) || 0;
        const newQuantity = currentQuantity + quantity;
        localStorage.setItem("tokenQuantity", newQuantity);
        setTokens(newQuantity);
        setQuantity(0);
        setPurchasedCoins(""); // clear input
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid quantity value");
    }
  };
```

Comment: stripe.redirecToCheckout is a deprecated method.  It is recommended you create Checkout Sessions using your back-end server: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout

You shared your code but not where the error is occurring or what error is being thrown.  If you could provide more detail (which line throws the error, what is the error text), that would.help.

Comment: There are no errors, on the stripe dashboard payment goes successfully. I can't update tokens. I deleted the backend and only focused on the stripe redirect. did some modifications here is the updated code. the code only updates once and on refresh it still becomes 0.

Comment: Okay so the payment part of this works?